# How to change current user to www in ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, users

Anyone knows?

```
root@fsdfssfewgfdgfng1:~# su www
Cannot execute /sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
root@fsdfssfewgfdgfng1:~# id www
uid=1000(www) gid=1000(www) groups=1000(www)
```

Comment: There is no need ever to login as `www`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RoVo i have a website it owned by www:www, if i upload the files using root, it will be root:root for those uploaded files, so i want to upload the file using www

Comment: Add a "set group id" permission to folders in www, and uploaded files will be root:www, make them readable by group if needed.

Comment: But better to not use root, make ownership someuser:www and upload files by someuser